# Codeigniter View -Insert Stament

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, view, insert

Codeigniter- insert stamen in a view

How have an insert statement in view?

In selecting I have this query in one of my views in codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM seminarattendee');
$number_of_attendee=$query->num_rows();
```

it outputs the number of rows in my table "seminarattendee"

this time I want to insert in a table

What I'm gonna put in my **$query**?

Comment: $query->result_array(); to get all the results. please and please read the docs.

Comment: What value do u want to insert

Answer (score 0):

This wil help you

Model

```
  public function record_count() {        
    $this->db->from('seminarattendee');
    $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return  $num_results;
        }
```

In controller

```
 $count['count']=$this->model->record_count();
    $this->load->view('viewpage',$count);
```